# Stacking different elements in a Windows.Forms.Button

Tags: c#, image, winforms, button, alignment

I am developing a windows forms application in c#. I am creating a large amount of buttons in loops, and I wish for both an image (icon), and text to be displayed on a button. I have experimented with alignment, but I require the image to be on the very top of the `Button`, and the text to be below the image. My current code is:

```
button1.Image = im;
button1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
button1.Text = "CS: GO";
button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

This produces this image, which is clearly not what I want:

[image]

I cannot resize the `Button`, as the text is user defined, and subject to change in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
```

if this doesn't fit your needs there's another Property:

```
button1.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText;
```

if I am right this will override **some** of your alignments.

Comment: Yeah, but that positions it at the bottom of the button. For a couple of reasons, I need it anchored below the image.

Comment: @jezza This should solve it :P - just keep the rest centered and it'll be fine :D

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, perfect. Also, thank you to whoever made edits to my question, I understand why it should of been windows forms.